# Use defaults to edit preferences

Tags: macos, terminal, preferences, defaults

Recently, I have been playing around with editing System Preferences without GUI and using the defaults command. I have tried for example:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide NO
```

Though that did not do anything. The preference was still checked in System Preferences, and the plist did not get edited when I opened it in Xcode. Even after relaunch of Finder and restart.

Am I using defaults properly? And if no, what is the proper use of it, when I am aiming to edit Preferences through terminal?

---

I am using OS X Mavericks (10.9.5)

Comment: Did an update as I realised an error in your code as well as the killAll in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command is adding a BOOL true or false.

So you needed to declare it as such by adding `-bool`. Otherwise you are changing to a string.

But also with this change you need to relaunch the dock for it to pick up the changes. You can do this by adding a second command.

```
killAll Dock
```

In one command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide  -bool no;killAll Dock
```

This will run your command and kill any process named Dock. The Dock will then auto relaunch picking up the changes.

Comment: thanks. And I suspect that it is the same for integers. Do you declare them with -int ?

Comment: Yes that is correct you should read the man page on defaults https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html   You can also type in terminal `man defaults` to see it